# Error en ".ExecuteNonQuery(); " c# .net

Tags: html, c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Tengo este error que ando revisando varias veces y veo que está bien, pero me sale error. Les comento un poco. Me lleva a la página editar y puedo editar los datos que quiera ya sea imagen o texto. Pero cuando solo quiero editar un texto y ya no la imagen me manda a una página de error y me menciona este error " cmdActualizarNoticia.ExecuteNonQuery();". Estoy realizando un crud y bueno solo me falta esto, espero me pueda ayudar y gracias de antemano :). Aquí esta mi crud:

```
using web2mayo.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using web2mayo.Datos;
using Renci.SshNet;    
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
    
namespace web2mayo.Controllers
{
    public class AdminNoticiaController : Controller
    {   
        static string cadena = "data source=ESTSIST03;Initial Catalog=WebH2Mayo;Persist Security Info=True; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        //NO CREAR ESTO HASTA LA VISTA DE INDEX
        //using ProyectoCarga.Models;
        static List<NoticiaModel> olista = new List<NoticiaModel>();

        //1.-PRIMERO CREAR LA VISTA DE SUBIR

        public ActionResult Subir()
        {
            return View();   
        }

        public IActionResult InformacionNoticia()
        {
            olista = new List<NoticiaModel>();

            using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(cadena))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Noticias", oconexion);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                oconexion.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {    
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {   
                        NoticiaModel archivo_encontrado = new NoticiaModel();
                        archivo_encontrado.IdNoticia = Convert.ToInt32(dr["IdNoticia"]);
                        archivo_encontrado.TituloCorto = dr["TituloCorto"].ToString();
                        archivo_encontrado.DescripcionCorta = dr["DescripcionCorta"].ToString();
                        archivo_encontrado.Fecha = dr["Fecha"].ToString();
                        archivo_encontrado.DescripcionLarga = dr["DescripcionLarga"].ToString();
                        archivo_encontrado.Imagen = dr["Imagen"] as byte[];
                        archivo_encontrado.ImagenLarga = dr["ImagenLarga"] as byte[];
                        archivo_encontrado.Extension = dr["Extension"].ToString();


                        olista.Add(archivo_encontrado);
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(olista);
        }
    
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubirArchivo(string TituloCorto, string DescripcionCorta,
            string Fecha, string DescripcionLarga, IFormFile Archivo)
        {
            olista = new List<NoticiaModel>();
            if (Archivo != null && Archivo.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    string Extension = Path.GetExtension(Archivo.FileName);

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        Archivo.CopyTo(ms);
                        byte[] data = ms.ToArray();

                        using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(cadena))
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Noticias(TituloCorto, DescripcionCorta, Fecha, " +
                                "DescripcionLarga, Imagen, ImagenLarga, Extension) " +
                                "VALUES(@TituloCorto,@DescripcionCorta,@Fecha,@DescripcionLarga,@Imagen,@ImagenLarga,@Extension)", oconexion);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TituloCorto", TituloCorto);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescripcionCorta", DescripcionCorta);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Fecha);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescripcionLarga", DescripcionLarga);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen", data);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagenLarga", data);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Extension", Extension);
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                            oconexion.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }

                    // Redirige después de completar la operación
                    return RedirectToAction("InformacionNoticia", "AdminNoticia");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Maneja el error
                    TempData["ErrorSubirArchivo"] = $"Error al subir el archivo: {ex.Message}";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Manejar el caso en que no se proporciona ningún archivo.
                TempData["ErrorSubirArchivo"] = "Por favor, seleccione un archivo.";
            }

            // Redirige a la vista de error
            return RedirectToAction("Error");
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public FileResult DescargarArchivo(int IdNoticia)
        {
            NoticiaModel oArchivo = olista.Where(a => a.IdNoticia == IdNoticia).FirstOrDefault();

            string NombreCompleto = oArchivo.TituloCorto + oArchivo.Extension;

            return File(oArchivo.Imagen, "application/" + oArchivo.Extension.Replace(".", ""), NombreCompleto);
        }


        private NoticiaModel ObtenerNoticiaPorId(int IdNoticia)
        {
            using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(cadena))
            {
                oconexion.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Noticias WHERE IdNoticia = @IdNoticia", oconexion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdNoticia", IdNoticia);

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        NoticiaModel noticia = new NoticiaModel
                        {
                            IdNoticia = Convert.ToInt32(dr["IdNoticia"]),
                            TituloCorto = dr["TituloCorto"].ToString(),
                            DescripcionCorta = dr["DescripcionCorta"].ToString(),
                            Fecha = dr["Fecha"].ToString(),
                            DescripcionLarga = dr["DescripcionLarga"].ToString(),
                            Imagen = dr["Imagen"] as byte[],
                            ImagenLarga = dr["ImagenLarga"] as byte[],
                            Extension = dr["Extension"].ToString()
                        };

                        return noticia;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null; // Si no se encuentra la noticia
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult EditarNoticia(int IdNoticia)
        {
            // Obtener la noticia por su IdNoticia desde la base de datos
            NoticiaModel noticia = ObtenerNoticiaPorId(IdNoticia);

            // Verificar si la noticia existe
            if (noticia != null)
            {
                // Mostrar la vista de edición con los datos actuales
                return View("EditarNoticia", noticia);
            }
            else
            {
                // Manejar el caso en que la noticia no existe
                return RedirectToAction("Error");
            }
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditarNoticia(int IdNoticia, string TituloCorto, string DescripcionCorta, string DescripcionLarga, IFormFile NuevaImagen)
        {
            olista = new List<NoticiaModel>();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // El modelo no es válido, manejar el error
                return View("EditarNoticia", ObtenerNoticiaPorId(IdNoticia));
            }

            using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(cadena))
            {
                // Verifica si se proporcionó una nueva imagen
                if (NuevaImagen != null && NuevaImagen.Length > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string Extension = Path.GetExtension(NuevaImagen.FileName);

                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            NuevaImagen.CopyTo(ms);
                            byte[] data = ms.ToArray();

                            SqlCommand cmdActualizarImagen = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Noticias SET Imagen = @Imagen, Extension = @Extension WHERE IdNoticia = @IdNoticia", oconexion);

                            cmdActualizarImagen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdNoticia", IdNoticia);
                            cmdActualizarImagen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen", data);
                            cmdActualizarImagen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Extension", Extension);

                            cmdActualizarImagen.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                            oconexion.Open();
                            cmdActualizarImagen.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Maneja el error
                        TempData["ErrorEditarImagen"] = $"Error al editar la imagen: {ex.Message}";
                        return RedirectToAction("Error");
                    }
                }

                // Actualiza los otros campos de la noticia siempre
                using (SqlCommand cmdActualizarNoticia = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Noticias SET TituloCorto = @TituloCorto, DescripcionCorta = @DescripcionCorta, " +
                   "DescripcionLarga = @DescripcionLarga WHERE IdNoticia = @IdNoticia", oconexion))
                {
                   
                    cmdActualizarNoticia.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdNoticia", IdNoticia);
                    cmdActualizarNoticia.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TituloCorto", TituloCorto);
                    cmdActualizarNoticia.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescripcionCorta", DescripcionCorta);
                    cmdActualizarNoticia.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescripcionLarga", DescripcionLarga);

                    cmdActualizarNoticia.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    cmdActualizarNoticia.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }


            }

            // Redirige después de completar la operación de edición
            return RedirectToAction("InformacionNoticia", "AdminNoticia");
        }



        public IActionResult EliminarNoticia(int IdNoticia)
        {
            olista = new List<NoticiaModel>();

            using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(cadena))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Noticias WHERE IdNoticia = @IdNoticia", oconexion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdNoticia", IdNoticia);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                oconexion.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("InformacionNoticia");
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Me parece que te falta abrir la conexión. Pero sería importante que compartas el error completo.

Comment: Deberias colocar el error completo, para saber si es algo en la conexion, en la consulta SQL, algo del motor, de las restricciones de la DB. Asi te podremos ayudar mejor.